# Can zsh kill-word ignore escaped spaces?

Tags: zsh

I want kill-word to turn `ls Dir\ A/Long\ File\ Name` into `ls Dir\ A/` if I call it at the end of the line. I know I can delete to `/` by modifying `$WORDCHARS`, but I found no way to ignore escaped spaces.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I thought about that, but it doesn't appear to have a way to stop at a slash.

Comment: @Gilles. Oops, I had overlooked that part of the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to tell the built-in widget `backward-kill-word` (which kills the next word to the *left* of the cursor) to do that, but you can just roll your own:

```bsh
backward-kill-word() { 
  # LBUFFER -- all text left of the cursor
  # (z)     -- split into shell words
  # (A)     -- force the resulting words into an array
  # [-1]    -- take the right-most element
  # :t      -- strip all path ancestors from it
  # %       -- remove the shortest matching substring from the right
  LBUFFER=${LBUFFER%${${(zA)LBUFFER}[-1]:t}*} 
  zle -f kill  # Tell the Zsh Line Editor that we've killed text.
}
zle -N backward-kill-word  # Replace the default widget.
```

Replacing `kill-word` (which kills the next word to the *right* of the cursor) is pretty similar:

```bsh
kill-word() { 
  # RBUFFER -- all text to the right of the cursor
  # [1]     -- take the left-most element
  # :h1     -- strip all path descendants from it
  # #       -- remove the shortest matching substring from the left
  RBUFFER=${RBUFFER#*${${(zA)RBUFFER}[1]:h1}} 
  zle -f kill
}
zle -N kill-word
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind typing multiple keys, you can use `^R / ^K` to go back to the previous slash then kill to the end of the line. If there are more words after the cursor initially, you can use `^@ ^R / ESC-x kill-region RET` (unfortunately `kill-region` is not bound to a key by default; the Emacs binding of `^W` is given to `backward-kill-word` instead for compatibility with standard cooked tty bindings).

In vi mode, starting in command mode and ending in insert mode, you can use something like `T/C` to delete to the end of the line, or `vT/s` or `dT/s` to delete until the original cursor location inclusive.

---

[`select-word-style shell`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-match_002dwords_002dby_002dstyle) may be of interest to you: it causes word motion to use shell syntax.

```
autoload -Uz select-word-style
select-word-style shell
```

Unfortunately it doesn't solve your problem because a slash is part of the word. I can't see a way to leverage it to stop at certain characters within words without changing the code of `match-words-by-style`.